# nginx - How often was accessed to specific file or path?

Tags: nginx, bash, logging, shell, log-files

I'm looking for a command/line to get the information how often was a specific file/path accessed from the web-server. (source: default access-log from nignx)

It should check all logs (current and compressed one) and returning a number or all entrys from the log files with the specific file/path.

**Reason:** I want to clear an old business webspace from his dead-files. Many files are/was used years ago for external use. (like newsletters, listings). Other seems to be duplicates who could be only for testing-purposes of the old administrators.

---

**Additional Information:**

OS: Debian Jessie (x64)

Server: nginx/1.6.2

Location: /var/logs/nginx/

Compression of log-files: gzip

Files:

```
2825674 | myDomainName_access.log
3895051 | myDomainName_access.log.1
 106353 | myDomainName_access.log.2.gz
 244729 | myDomainName_access.log.3.gz
 143118 | myDomainName_access.log.4.gz
  55763 | myDomainName_access.log.5.gz
```

---

**Example INPUT**

You've to go into the root of your domain.tld and enter the following command:

(just only an very simplified example)

```
user@host:/var/www/domain.tld# filesInLogCheck /var/logs/nginx/domain-access.* subfolder/index.php
```

**OUTPUT**

```
x.x.x.x - - [07/Mar/2016:10:13:29 +0100] "/subfolder/handle.php HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "https://domain.tld/subfolder/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0"
x.x.x.x - - [07/Mar/2016:10:16:37 +0100] "/subfolder/handle.php HTTP/1.1" 200 104 "https://domain.tld/subfolder/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0"
x.x.x.x - - [07/Mar/2016:10:21:39 +0100] "GET /subfolder/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12589 "https://domain.tld/subfolder/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0"
x.x.x.x - - [11/Mar/2016:11:18:36 +0100] "/subfolder/handle.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1206 "https://domain.tld/subfolder/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
x.x.x.x - - [11/Mar/2016:11:19:05 +0100] "/subfolder/handle.php HTTP/1.1" 200 129 "https://domain.tld/subfolder/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
x.x.x.x - - [11/Mar/2016:11:19:49 +0100] "/subfolder/handle.php HTTP/1.1" 200 120 "https://domain.tld/subfolder/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
x.x.x.x - - [11/Mar/2016:11:22:09 +0100] "GET /subfolder/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16008 "https://domain.tld/subfolder/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
x.x.x.x - - [11/Mar/2016:11:27:49 +0100] "/subfolder/handle.php HTTP/1.1" 200 468 "https://domain.tld/subfolder/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
x.x.x.x - - [11/Mar/2016:11:28:03 +0100] "GET /subfolder/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16007 "https://domain.tld/subfolder/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
x.x.x.x - - [11/Mar/2016:11:28:24 +0100] "/subfolder/handle.php HTTP/1.1" 200 468 "https://domain.tld/subfolder/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
```

**Or cleaner OUTPUT:**

```
[07/Mar/2016:10:13:29 +0100] | "/subfolder/handle.php" | "https://domain.tld/subfolder/index.php" 
[07/Mar/2016:10:16:37 +0100] | "/subfolder/handle.php" | "https://domain.tld/subfolder/index.php" 
[07/Mar/2016:10:21:39 +0100] | "GET /subfolder/" | "https://domain.tld/subfolder/index.php"
[11/Mar/2016:11:18:36 +0100] | "/subfolder/handle.php" | "https://domain.tld/subfolder/"
[11/Mar/2016:11:19:05 +0100] | "/subfolder/handle.php" | "https://domain.tld/subfolder/"
[11/Mar/2016:11:19:49 +0100] | "/subfolder/handle.php" | "https://domain.tld/subfolder/"
[11/Mar/2016:11:22:09 +0100] | "GET /subfolder/" | "https://domain.tld/subfolder/"
[11/Mar/2016:11:27:49 +0100] | "/subfolder/handle.php" | "https://domain.tld/subfolder/index.php"
[11/Mar/2016:11:28:03 +0100] | "GET /subfolder/" | "https://domain.tld/subfolder/index.php"
[11/Mar/2016:11:28:24 +0100] | "/subfolder/handle.php" | "https://domain.tld/subfolder/"
```

Comment: One thing you must provide more information, are the file name is present in the nginx access logs you are talking about, have you tried any thing, any command , have you googled it. Are all the logs present in the same directory. What is the compression you have used. what is the total size of compressed logs. And no there isn't a single command which will complete your task in one line, you have to implement some logic in it.

Comment: Hello, I added the addional information. If I had found something on google, I wouldn't asking. The log files and files I want to check aren't in the same folder.

Comment: Do you need some specific file types? For example images only png/jpg/svg.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly the command could be

```
$ grep GET access.log | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d '?' -f 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -r -n -k 1 | head -10
 114179 /bitrix/spread.php
  13208 /bitrix/tools/public_session.php
  11945 /
   4393 /accessories/cases/
   2268 /search/
   2079 /ajax/actions.php
   1951 /shop/
   1591 /search
   1388 /apple-watch/
   1267 /apple-iphone/iphone-6s/
```

the command will show you top 10 most visited links. If you really need all links just remove 'head -10'.

For gz files you can use the following one

```
$ zcat access.log.gz | grep GET | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d '?' -f 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -r -n -k 1 | head -10
```

> And no there isn't a single command which will complete your task in one line

you are wrong, one line script. Pipelines in bash are really powerful ;)

```
# zcat -f -- /var/log/httpd/* | grep GET | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d '?' -f 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -r -n -k 1 | head -10 | awk '{SUM+=$1;print $0} END{print "Total hits: "SUM}'
  15249 /sites/all/modules/lightbox2/js/lightbox.js
    173 /scripts/template/
    128 /libs/bundler.php
    125 /libs/jquery.min.js
     60 /vSample
Total hits: 15735
```

More universal script

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly LOG_DIR='/var/log/nginx'
readonly TOPS=5
readonly METHOD='GET|POST'

/bin/zcat -f -- ${LOG_DIR}/* | grep -E "${METHOD}" | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d '?' -f 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -r -n -k 1 | head -${TOPS} | awk '{SUM+=$1;print $0} END{print "Total hits: "SUM}'
```

Test result

```
# ./tops.sh
  15249 /sites/all/modules/lightbox2/js/lightbox.js
    173 /scripts/template/
    128 /libs/bundler.php
    125 /libs/jquery.min.js
     60 /vSample
Total hits: 15735
```

Comment: Thanks you for the afford, nice to know! But want to check files against it entrys in the log-files. I will update the main topic with a command and output example.

Comment: With new amendments I don't understand what are you trying to achieve? Because I have parsed a log from one of our production system and one of url has 1kk hits. And you want that script list all of them?

Comment: Yes... I want that it lists all matches of my pattern (file with path), which appeard in the logs. (all of them) So I can see, when was the last time the file was accessed from outside (web) and how often. With that I can detect easly dead-files and can remove them. Move active/used files and redirect them and so on.